# CodeIgniter - jQuery; show/hide error class

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, error-handling

I have no idea how to start to implement this even though it's probably really simple.

I made a simple login form with CodeIgniter. The controller connects to the model, checks db for username/pass and redirects to the member area if the login is successful. However, I would like to show an error message ('Invalid blabla') when the login is not successful.

I basically want to have a hidden `<p class="error">` which I want to `show()` or `hide()`with jQuery. I'm new to CI and still trying to wrap my head around the framework, so combining it with jQuery is a bit confusing to me at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$('.error').hide();
$('div.hidden').hide();
$("#journal").submit(function() {
    // validate and process form
    // first hide any error messages
$('.error').hide();
```

From here on out do the rest of your jQuery then something like this if you are not using the validation class

```
var title = $("input#title").val();

if (title == "") {
        $("label#title_error").show();
        $("input#title").focus();
  return false;
}
```

your error label html will have a class of .error and a individual ID for titles, names, age etc

After re-reading your question this is not the proper response. If you are using Ajax, the showing of your error msg would be done in the Success part of your jQuery in the same manner as above

```
<label>Title</label>
<input type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" value="" name="title" id="title" />
<label class="error" for="title" id="title_error">This field is required.</label>
```